# javascripts objects dont work for assigning css styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

Only direct assignment of css styles work. passing via user defined variables is not working.Is it a syntax error or css styles cant be passed via user defined variables

```
<!-- using variable doesnt work -->
<body>
<p id="ref" onclick="display()">hello</p>
<script>
function display(){
var d = document.getElementById("ref").style.display;
d = "none";
}
</script>
</body>
```

---

```
<!-- direct assignment works -->
<body>
<p id="ref" onclick="display()">hello</p>
<script>
function display(){
document.getElementById("ref").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style.display` is not an object.  It's a property of an object and there is no way to directly store a reference to a property.

So, when you do:

```
var d = document.getElementById("ref").style.display;
d = "none";
```

All, you're doing is storing the string `"none"` into the variable `d`.  It isn't doing anything more than that.

Because `style` is an object, you can have a reference to it:

```
var s = document.getElementById("ref").style;
s.display = "none";
```

Though, other than exploring how things work here, there's no reason to use an intermediate variable at all here.  So, you may as well just simplify the code and do:

```
document.getElementById("ref").style.display = "none";
```

---

A reference worth reading: [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. It has to do with value versus references. When you did `var d = document.getElementById("ref").style.display;`, you created a copy of the value in a new variable. This means that `style.display` and `d` were then two variables with simply the same value. So after that, when you changed the value of d, the value of the other copy remained unchanged. That's why scenario 1 doesn't work, but scenario 2 does.

Here is a Stackoverflow topic that goes much deeper than what I explained : [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value).

Answer (score 1):

Here you are setting the value of the property `"display"` in variable `"d"` so `"d"` contains text value like `"none","block","inline-block" etc.` `not object` of an element. so you can't set property via variables.